# Why do I get CORS error when query string is different only

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, .net-core, cors

I'm getting a CORS error when I call the API and only the query string is different. The rest of them works well. ( Get, Post, Update, Delete)

But I could not understand what is differences between these two URLs in terms of CORS Policy:

*[It does not work]*
https://api.test-site.com/api/XYZ/query?type=Cat&startDate&startDate=01/06/2021&endDate=18/08/2021

and

*[It Works]* [https://api.test-site.com/api/ABC/query?startDate=&EndDate=&xstartDate=02/08/2021&xendDate=16/09/2021&dueStartDate=&dueEndDate=&lNumber=&es=[]&aUserIds=[]&pics=[]&kLevels=[]&rIds=[]](https://api.test-site.com/api/ABC/query?startDate=&EndDate=&xstartDate=02/08/2021&xendDate=16/09/2021&dueStartDate=&dueEndDate=&lNumber=&es=%5B%5D&aUserIds=%5B%5D&pics=%5B%5D&kLevels=%5B%5D&rIds=%5B%5D)

The first URL getting an Error below;

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.test-site.com/api/XYZ/query?type=Cat&startDate&startDate=01/06/2021&endDate=18/08/2021'
> from origin 'https://test-site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Can XYZ and ABC cause this error if not what is the reason for this error?

Clien-Side Code :

```
 return axios
     .get(this.apiBaseURL() + url, {
        headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': this.baseURL(),
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
     })
```

Server-Side Code

```
  app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins(new["https://api.test-site.com","https://api.test-site.com/api","https://test-site.com"] {}).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
```

Comment: Can you show your ABC and XYZ  action headers pls?

Comment: I've [HttpGet("query")] only on both controller(action).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this syntax

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                      builder =>
                       {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader();
              }));

        .....
            
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .....

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
           app.UseAuthorization();

            ....
         }
```

if it works then you can replace builder.AllowAnyOrigin with

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://api.test-site.com")
```

and remove

```
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': this.baseURL(),
```

it doesn't make any sense

Comment: I tried but I got an error like this--> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: @mocco Try to add .AllowCredentials() but I don't think it will help. Pls let me know

Comment: That's right, it gives this error; 'The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported

Comment: try to replace allorigins with builder.WithOrigins("https://api.test-site.com")

Comment: The error again this; "from origin 'https://test-site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: I think you put the wrong origin. It should be not api url, it should be an url your are calling API from.

Comment: I wish that but I've put all the URLs I've with HTTPS and HTTP. I'm not sure but It may be about the request headers on the client-side.

Comment: I've found something, "it's about return data". Because when I return bad request on the controller it called successfully. But still don't know why